# Android: handler not working

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am trying to load an object from a server in Android. This object is loaded in a thread. When loading is finished, an _objectHandler is called to get some key - values from the object, for example, the _filename key. Every time a filename is retrieved, I want to display it. For this reason, I am looping over the element of the loaded object in a second thread, and calling a _handler every time a value is loaded. What I want to get is all the _filename values, but what I am getting is only the last value of the _fielName. what I am doing wrong?

```
ArrayList <myObject> object;
String filename;

Thread thread = new Thread (MyActivity.this);
thread.start();


public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();
    try {
        object = getObjectFromServer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    _objectHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    Looper.loop();
}

Handler _objectHandler = new Handler() {
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
            myObject obj= object(i);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                      filename= obj.getFileName();
                      Message msg = new Message();
                      _handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                 }
            }).start();
        }
    }
};

Handler _handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.i("The fielname is ", " filename" + filename
    }
};
```

Comment: Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use android.os.Handler class. This will provide you a mechanism for enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.